# ¿Cómo aplicar la función apply() en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, funciones, pandas

Como puedo hacer una función que tome todos los valores numéricos de una fila, y lo haga para la siguiente

> ```
> >>> RP
>
>         AAPL         MSFT         XOM        JNJ         JPM          AMZN         GE        FB         T 
> 0     0.188478     0.068795    0.141632    0.147974    0.178185     0.040370   0.020516   0.047275  0.166774
> 1     0.236818     0.008540    0.082680    0.088380    0.453573     0.021001   0.014043   0.089811  0.005155
> 2     0.179750     0.071711    0.050107    0.089424    0.080108     0.106136   0.155139   0.073487  0.194138
> 3     0.214392     0.015681    0.034284    0.276342    0.118263     0.002101   0.057484   0.000317  0.281137
> ```

Por ejemplo, lo hice para la `fila cero`, de la siguiente manera

```
arr = RP.iloc[0].values.copy()
WeightedReturns = StockReturns.mul(arr, axis=1)
ReturnsDaily= WeightedReturns.sum(axis=1)
mean_retorns_daily = np.mean(ReturnsDaily)
Returns = ((1+mean_retorns_daily)**252)-1
cov_mat =StockReturns.cov()
cov_mat_annual = cov_mat*252
Volatility= np.sqrt(np.dot(arr.T, np.dot(cov_mat_annual, arr)))
```

donde `StockReturns` es un indice aparte que tengo. Busco obtener los `Returns`
y `Volatility` para cada fila distinta de RP, hacer lo mismo para las siguientes filas y guardar cada valar en columnas.

Lo ideal, pienso que seria a través de una función para lograrlo, pero la verdad estoy un poco confundido. Agradezco de ante mano su apoyo